# JOOMLA : template overrides for plugin

Tags: php, joomla

i'm doing a gallery plugin for joomla, someone told me to use template overrides, i really don't know what the hell is this, and why i need to use it for my gallery plugin? i did googling and found this article useful [Joomla template override](http://newtojoomla.com/pages/visual/override_footer/index.htm) , but still i am not able understand why i need this, and how to do this for my gallery plugin 'cause the example i found is for modules, your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to insert some content (a gallery) into the output via a plugin, template overrides are not what you need. Template overrides would allow you to modify the output of a component or a module, but not to insert a functionality like a gallery. You simply want to create a plugin that acts on onContentPrepare.